# Jquery templates, escape "${...}"

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, jquery-templates

I have a piece of javascript code as follows:

```
var data = { ... };
var template = "<select>" +
                 "<option value='${0:###,###.##}'>Format as $</option>" + 
               "</select>";

$.tmpl(template, data).appendTo("#placeholder");
```

My problem is that I want to evaluate the "value='${0:###,###.##}'" as a string, but jQuery templates attempts to evaluate it as an object reference.

Is there a way to escape the ${} characters?

Cheers, Shane

Comment: have you tried using single quotes, or putting a backslash before the $ sign?

Comment: with \$ ? so it becomes `<option value='\$... etc`

Comment: Backslash doesn't work, and neither does $$. I don't see where I can put a single quote, can you give an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to replace $ with its special HTML character `&#36;`

```
var data = { };
var template = "<select>" +
         "<option value='&#36;{0:###,###.##}'>Format as $</option>" + 
       "</select>";

$.tmpl( template, data).appendTo("#placeholder");
```